# What are the dimensions of the inscribed rectangle for the iPhone X?

Tags: iphone, display

The iPhone has traditionally had a display that is rectangular, every pixel of which can be used to display content.

The X changes things to be a bit more like the original Macintoshes, with rounded corners and an infamous notch. Within this uneven shape, there is a maximum sized rectangle that can be displayed. (On older phones, this rectangle is equal to the total display area, but that is no longer true.)

What are the dimensions of the iPhoneX's inscribed rectangle, in physical pixels, inches?